# Do there exist "weak ring homomorphisms" that aren't (genuine) ring homomorphisms?

Tags: ring-theory

(All my rings have $1$, and all my ring homomorphisms preserve $1$.)

Suppose $R$ is a ring. Philosophically, it may be the case that $R$ has too many zero divisors for a particular method "$\mu$" of studying it to work. One way to rectify this is to try to find a bigger ring $S$ together with a surjective ring homomorphism $S \rightarrow R$, and then applying method $\mu$ to $S$, and then finally using this to deduce something about $R$.

Here's a very different idea. By a weak ring homomorphism $f:R \rightarrow S$, lets mean a function satisfying the following axioms.

1. $f(a+b) = f(a)+f(b)$
2. $f(0) = 0$
3. $f(ab) = f(a)f(b)$ unless $ab=0$.
4. $f(1) = 1$ unless $1=0$.

The weakening of condition $4$ buys us nothing; it could equally well read "$f(1)=1$". But it seems possible that the weakening of condition 3 gives an interesting notion.

Returning to the opening idea, suppose that $R$ has too many zero divisors for a particular method "$\mu$" of studying it to work. We can try to rectify this by finding a bigger ring $S$ together with an injective **weak** ring homomorphism $R \rightarrow S$, applying method $\mu$ to $S$, and then finally using this to deduce something about $R$.

But, I'm unsure as to whether or not such things actually exist:

> **Question.** Do there exist "weak ring homomorphisms" that aren't (genuine) ring homomorphisms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this buys you nothing. If you have $ab=0$ with $a,b\ne 0$, then $(a-1)b$ will be nonzero, so we still get
$$ f(ab) = f((a-1)b+b) = f(a-1)f(b)+f(b) = (f(a)-1)f(b)+f(b) = f(a)f(b) $$

Comment: "Disappointing. But not unexpected." -The Merovingian (Matrix Revolutions)

Comment: Nice proof, by the way.